# I need help understanding the notation of a question regarding 2 functions

Tags: functions, notation

In my homework, there were 2 functions defined as such:

*f((x,y))=x-y , f:ℕ^2→ℤ*

*g((x,y))=(x-y,x+y) , g:ℕ^2→ℕ^2*

I was asked to prove whether the functions are injective, surjective and find their Image, which I did.  But in the next section, I was asked to find "*f ∘ g*" and "*g ∘ g*", and I have no clue what this notation means because the teacher never used it during the lessons.
Does it mean something about the domain and codomain of the functions?

Comment: This is called "composition of functions". For example, $f \circ g$ means "first do $g$ and then do $f$.

Answer (score 2):

I found out what ∘ means: it's a composition of 2 functions.

> For example, f∘g of the functions *f(x)=x^2 f:A → B* and *g(y)=y+1  f:B → C*

> *f(g(y)) = f(y+1) = (y+1)^2 f: A → C*